# C++ Function Defined in Lib, But Referenced Through DLL

Tags: c++, dll, export, lib

I'm using Visual Studio 2022.

I have a function `foo()` in a static library called `MyLib`.

```
void foo();
```

I have a DLL `MyDLL` which references `MyLib`.  It does not make any calls to `foo()`.

I have an executable which loads the DLL.  When I try to access the function `foo()` from the executable, it returns NULL.

```
void* pFoo = GetProcAddress(hMyTestDll, "foo");
if (pFoo)
{
    // Call pFoo()
}
else
{
    throw "foo() not found";
}
```

I understand the function needs to be exported.  But, is there a way I can make the executable know that `foo()` (from the static library) exists without writing the function in the DLL?  Can you export functions from the DLL if they were defined in a `.lib` that it references?

Comment: `foo` is not exported by your DLL. Furthermore, there is no guarantee that `foo` even _exists_ in the DLL, since it's not called anywhere and so the linker will probably exclude it (unless perhaps it's called indirectly in MyLib by something that your DLL _does_ use, and is not inlined). Bottom line is you can't get at it through any legitimate means. The executable that uses this must link against `MyLib` if it wishes to call `foo`. Or the DLL must export a function that wraps `foo`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!  It's not the answer I was hoping for.  But, at least I can stop scratching my head.